# jQuery.getScript vs yepnope performance

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, yepnope

I googled quite a lot looking for the answer to this question but didn't find anything.

Aside of additionnal functionalities offered by a script loader like yepnope, is it going to give me better performance and better cache management than jQuery.getScript?

Thanks in advance,

Simon

Comment: note that by default `jQuery.getScript()` uses `cache: false` which will hurt performance the second load of a page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In principle, their functionally the same. The biggest gain you get from something like yepnope is integrated conditional loading. Whereas, with $.getScript, you'd have to do any requisite boolean checks manually. There's also little things like the fact that yepnope is already supported by tests, whereas if you wanted the same certainty in your custom conditional-loading code, you'd have to write your own.

In short, yepnope is just a time-saver like jQuery itself is a time-saver. There's nothing you can do in jQuery that you can't do in vanilla JavaScript; it just takes more time, energy, and effort. If you're thinking about dynamically loading scripts, I would recommend that you use a library for that, instead of re-inventing the wheel.

Interestingly, yepnope is actually bundled into Modernizr (I didn't know that). So, if you're looking to start getting into HTML5, you can include Modernizr and get your shivs, feature-sensing sugar, and dynamic script loading all in one.

Comment: I'm already using Modernizr and this is why I was looking closer at yepnope. The main thing I reproach to jQuery.getScript is that on first loading, it (or at least it seem's that it) doesn't include header like etag because it doesn't know them and so refetch the full script even if you already get it the day before and still have it in your cache. Does this would still be the case with a lib like yepnope which doesn't use ajax request to load the script?

Comment: Yepnope *does* use AJAX to load the script, and it in fact requires your server to return expires headers to function properly. Etags aren't really used for anything. If you're already using Modernizr, though, it's a no-brainer. The functionality is already there, it's silly to not use it and write your own from scratch instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answers, I have no more questions sir ;-)

Comment: FYI [yepnope does not use AJAX to load scipts](https://github.com/SlexAxton/yepnope.js/blob/v1.5.4/yepnope.js#L71)

Answer (score 1):

You can also use head.js if you are loading multiple JS files.